# Is the series $\sum 5^n/(4^n+3)$ convergent or not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $\sum \dfrac{5^n}{4^n +3}$ convergent or divergent?

Actually I have started the problem by applying the root test but got stuck so as what to do with the denominator.

If there is any other method to apply please tell me that.

Comment: are you talking about the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5^n}{4^n+3}$ or the sequence $\left(\frac{5^n}{4^n+3}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ ?

Comment: I am asking about the series !

Answer (score 3):

As a **sequence**, 
$$\frac{5^n}{4^n+3}\to\infty \mbox{ as }n\to\infty. $$
In particular, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{5^n}{4^n+3}\neq 0.$$
Therefore, the **series**
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{4^n+3}$$
diverges by [divergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Answer (score 2):

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty }\frac{5^n}{4^n+3} \neq 0$$
therefore the series can't converge.

Indeed, for all $n$,
$$\frac{5^n}{4^n+3}\geq \frac{4^n}{4^n+3}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{4^n}}\underset{n\to\infty }{\longrightarrow  }1.$$

and thus $$\limsup_{n\to\infty }\frac{5^n}{4^n+1}\geq 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5^n}{4^n+3}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n}{3 \times 4^{-n}+1}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n$$
as  $4^{-n}$ tends to $0.$

Now $\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n$ is a continuous function, so
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^n=\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n}=\infty.$$

So the sequence diverges, which implies that the series diverges as well.